# Automate inkscape "resize to content"

Tags: inkscape

I'm looking for a way to run inkscape in batch mode (without GUI) to apply the "resize to content" GUI action to an SVG from the command line.
I'm in 1.3 (so verbs are not an option) on Linux. Is there a sequence of actions to do that?
Obviously, these is because I need to apply this to 100's of SVG.

Comment: Hi. Do you mean like Edit > Select all, then Edit > Resize Page to Selection?  I've no idea if you could use these from the command line though. Maybe someone over at Unix & Linux stack exchange/Stack Overflow would know.

Comment: No need for select all. The document is larger than the content. It's a conversion to SVG of a PDF that was created from a PPTX by someone who used "print as pdf" instead of "save as pdf". So there are two white bands. One on top and one below of each slide.
If you open the svg of a single slide in gui mode and just resize to content, the document returns to the original 16/9 slide dimensions. No need to select anything. Just save.

Comment: Yeah, but if you want to use another sequence of actions within Inkscape, then you need to make a selection first before applying resize page to selection (this is not the same as resize to content available within the document properties dialog). "Resize page to selection" requires that a selection be made.  Unfortunately I can't tell you if it's even possible to use these from the command line, and coding is generally off-topic here, which is why I suggest you might want to reach out to the other stack exchange communities.

Comment: @BillyKerr 'Resize Page to Selection' resizes "to the current selection *or the drawing if there is no selection*". See my screenshot below. Also, there is the `select-all` action, so if it did need a selection, then you could simply use `--actions="...;select-all:all;page-fit-to-selection"`.

Comment: @Xrott - I stand corrected. That's good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manipulate a document before saving from the command-line, you use the `--actions="..."` option with a list of action-ids separated by semicolons (`;`).

To find out the id of an operation from inside Inkscape, you can use the command-palette. However, first you need to open the preferences, go to 'Interface → Command Palette' and enable the 'Show command line argument names' setting. You'll have to restart Inkscape for it to take effect.

Now press <kbd>?</kbd> to open the command-palette (depending on your keyboard layout, you may also need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>) and search for `resize` for example to get the `app.page-fit-to-selection` action (the `app.` prefix can be omitted). You can even click on the id to copy it to the clipboard.

[image: Screenshot of Inkscape's command-palette with 'Resize Page to Selection' operation highlighted]

All in all, your command should look something like this:

```
inkscape --actions="page-fit-to-selection" -o "./output.svg" "./input.svg"
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your SVG documents and convert them as follows:

**On Unix-like system**:

```
for f in *.svg; do inkscape -D -o  resized_${f} $f; done
```

**On Windows (using Powershell)**:

```
gci *.svg | % { inkscape -D -o ("resized_" + $_.Name) $_.FullName }
```

#### Example:

If you have a directory with the following content:

```
doc1.svg
doc2.svg
doc3.svg
```

The result after running the command above will be:

```
doc1.svg
doc2.svg
doc3.svg
resized_doc1.svg
resized_doc2.svg
resized_doc3.svg
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work too. However, the page dimensions are preserved.  In your browser, only the document is displayed. However in inkscape GUI, the page is unchanged. This is different from the [accepted solution](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/163151/47819).  Still upvoted.

Comment: @AlainPannetier: The command above works as expected. Not sure what issues you're encountering.

Comment: @AlainPannetier: Could you share a screenshot? I can't reproduce the issue you're encountering.